# NorthSouthContainer layout sizing in GXT

Tags: gwt, extjs, gxt

I'm trying to create a simple page example with a menu bar on top and a `BorderLayoutContainter` on the bottom. I cannot figure out how to get the bottom part automatically fit into the size left over.

I have something like this:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    MenuBar mbar = new MenuBar();
    // Add menus...

    BorderLayoutContainer blc = new BorderLayoutContainer();
    // Create borderlayout parts...

    NorthSouthContainer mainCon = new NorthSouthContainer();
    mainCon.addNorthWidget(mbar);
    mainCon.addSouthWidget(blc);

    ViewPort vp = new ViewPort();
    vp.add(mainCon);
    RootPanel.get().add(vp);
}
```

The menu bar display properly but the bottom - the `BorderLayoutContainer` - is completely squashed. If I just add the `BorderLayoutContainer` to the `ViewPort`, it displays properly, i.e. fills the entire screen.

Why is the size not getting passed from the `NorthSouthContainer`'s south part to the `BorderLayoutContainer`. Or is there something else going on?

Comment: which version of GXT are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue some weeks ago. It seems to be a bug in GXT where at someplace the widgets' css is not correctly `ensureInjected()`. As you know, your north- and southwidget take their height attribute from the parent container. You could avoid this error by passing style-attributes to the inner widgets like so:

```
mbar.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("height", "50%");
blc.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("height", "50%");
```

Of course I know this is not a really clean solution but it is a possibility. If you want full access to the solution, you need to implement your own appearance to the BorderLayoutContainer. Phew...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. As a workaround, if you wrap the south widget into another Viewport instance it works for me (using GXT 3.1.1).

Answer (score 0):

Its an official bug. You can try using VerticalLayoutContainer as follow-

```
VerticalLayoutContainer vlc = new VerticalLayoutContainer();
vlc.add(mBar,new VerticalLayoutData(1,-1));
vlc.add(blc,new VerticalLayoutData(1,1));
```

See more on [VerticalLayoutData](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/container/VerticalLayoutContainer.VerticalLayoutData.html) here